# How to store debug variables in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to store debug variables while using a breakpoint and restore them regardless of the application. I probably need some plugin to let me serialize variables and restore them anytime.

To be more specific I want:

1. breakpoint
2. see variables, store them
3. let the flow go further
4. restore variables and view them in a convenient way (maybe in debug, but not while debugging) and compare variables with my application's view tier

ps. I was trying to find some plugin, but without results.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completetly agree with stacker, to answer for your next question about expand all it's very hard to implement for eclipse guys - regarding to [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Expand_Selected_Variables_Button_in_Debug)

> One risk is the difficulty of dealing
>   with self-referencing structures,
>   because application have to expand
>   them only one time. There may be
>   variable A which has a reference to B;
>   and there may be a variable B which
>   has a reference to A. This kind of
>   problems -seem- can easily solve by a
>   set, however this isn't the best
>   approach. Another risk may be the
>   quantity of the features I proposed. I
>   think it would be better to withdraw
>   some of these. I published them here,
>   because I couldn't determine which.

Comment: Yes, you're right about self-referencing structures. The only possible way to implement that is to let go only a few levels down. Anyway thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do (using the standard debugger) is, to copy the textual information from the variables view into the clipboard (Ctrl-C) and store (Ctrl-V) it in a texteditor for later reference. Please note that only expanded nodes, from the variables view, will be copied.

Comment: I know that, but that is useless since you cannot expand all variables in one click.